# How to change the width of a jitter graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
jitter <- ggplot(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ],
                 aes(x=cut, y=price, color=clarity)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.5)
```

The result is quite awful, all the point stick together. Is there any function to stretch the x axis to a nice way? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by stretch the x axis to a nice way? What does your desired output look like?

Comment: Hi Mhammer, as you can see below, the graph is too narrow.

Comment: I uploaded the picture in my original post.

Comment: Just scale your Rstudio window for a better preview. To save the plot you can specify width and height to solve this problem. Either in the IDE clicking 'export' or using e.g. `ggsave("image.png", jitter, width = 6, height = 4)` which saves the plot to your working directory.

Comment: Hi JaySf, you are so right. It is about the preview issue. I solve this problem by enlarging the preview window.